# How to use AtlassianWikiRenderer in jira

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, wiki-markup

In jdoc 8.0.1 I see [com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.wiki.AtlassianWikiRenderer](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.0.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/renderer/wiki/AtlassianWikiRenderer.html)
But I can't import it:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.wiki.AtlassianWikiRenderer;

> .... package com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.wiki does not exist
```

How can I use AtlassianWikiRenderer.render(...) in my own render?
The same with com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.renderer.text.DefaultTextRenderer

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. You need to have jira-core uncommented out in your pom.xml file